# php save array mutlidimensional

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I develop a module under prestashop and I am looking to record a multidimensional table in a bdd.

I have a vendor column with a unique ID and row groups with a unique ID.
I have to fill in information in each box:

[image: table]

when I fill in some input the var_dump returns me this:
[image: dump]

The first number is the group ID and the second number is the supplier ID.

I am trying to save this information in a table that looks like this:

[image: bdd]

To save it I would go through a class that I created new Objectif()

Here is the code I have already done. but I'm blocking on the recordings:

```
public function postProcess()
{
    $obj = new Objectif();

    if (Tools::isSubmit('objectif')) {
        foreach ($_POST as $k => $item) {
            $explo = explode('_', $k);
            $group_id = $explo[0];
            $supplier_id = $explo[1];

            if ($group_id != '' && $supplier_id != '' && $item != '') {
                $obj->id_group = $group_id;
                $obj->id_supplier = $supplier_id;
                $obj->objs = $item;
                $obj->save();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you always have this pattern `group_id _ supplier_id`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $item) {
    $obj = new Objectif();
    $explo = explode('_', $k);
    $group_id = $explo[0];
    $supplier_id = $explo[1];

    if ($group_id != '' && $supplier_id != '' && $item != '') {
        $obj->id_group = $group_id;
        $obj->id_supplier = $supplier_id;
        $obj->objs = $item;
        $obj->save();
    }
}
```

Now you have all information you need.

Comment: I try this too but it adds only one line in the comic. I updated my code

Comment: you need to put `$obj = new Objectif();` inside the foreach loop

Comment: it works but it saves the same value several times in the bdd

Comment: it does not crush the old value that adds a line

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Save the data in the database but if I modify a data it crushes the old

Comment: And how do you know if the data you are trying to modify is the same? Use this logic to find in the database and set the `id_obj` to the `$obj` object, then save. It will update the old data.

Comment: I do not pass id_obj in my function. You mean I'm doing this way $obj = new Objectif($ id_obj)?